# Plotly Parameter config of io.to_html() gives TypeError: to_html() got multiple values for argument 'config'

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

First time asking here. Any question guideline that I might forget, please let me know.

I am trying to get the HTML string of a Figure to produce a HTML report with static graphs. SVG/PNG format doesn't work for me because the annotations doesn't stay on [write_image()](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html#plotly.io.write_image) the way that I need, by rounding float numbers. I've searched for it but my search string didn't get me an answer.

So I tried to use [io.to_html()](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html#plotly.io.to_html) and it works fine with all the other parameters but the config option. The strange thing is, in [write_html()](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html#plotly.io.write_html) it works fine and is the same parameter.

How can I make it work? Where am I wrong?

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007").query("continent == 'Europe'")
df.loc[df['pop'] < 2.e6, 'country'] = 'Other countries' # Represent only large countries
fig = px.pie(df, values='pop', names='country', title='Population of European continent')

config = {'staticPlot': True, 'displayModeBar': False}

fig.show(config=config)
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', config=config) #this works

fig.to_html('first_figure.html', config=config) #this doesn't works
```

> TypeError: to_html() got multiple values for argument 'config'
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /var/folders/6p/1cm_yr512ld62_2fl_jf34km0000gn/T/ipykernel_82667/3638723120.py
> in 
> 9 fig.write_html('first_figure.html', config=config)
> 10
> ---> 11 fig.to_html('first_figure.html', config=config)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/deku/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py
> in to_html(self, *args, **kwargs)    3584         import plotly.io as
> pio    3585
> -> 3586         return pio.to_html(self, *args, **kwargs)    3587     3588     def write_html(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> TypeError: to_html() got multiple values for argument 'config'

Comment: it appears to work if you pass as an **arg** instead of **kwarg** `fig.to_html('first_figure.html', config)` was looking for implementation code to explain but can't find it

Comment: @RobRaymond thanks!!!! It worked for me!!! Almost forgot to answer you.